# How can I get the download URL in String from firebase storage inside "addOnSuccessListener"

Tags: android, firebase-storage

This is my approach to upload an image file and getting the download link

```
UploadTask uploadTask = profileImageRef.putBytes(data);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                String fileUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Uploaded Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }});
```

When I logged `fileUrl` it displays a String like this

`com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@6ee8ba8`

Someone please give me a solution to get the download url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this,

```
UploadTask uploadTask = profileImageRef.putBytes(data);

    Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
        } else {
            // Handle failures
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @4C3 got it? or any doubts.